# why we need validate-issuer in azure B2C passport?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD B2C in node, I want to know that why we use validateIssuer = true or false?

```
passport.use(new BearerStrategy({

    isB2C: true,
    validateIssuer: false,
    loggingLevel: 'trace',
    passReqToCallback: false,
}
```

if i make it false it send me warning to make true in production environment so why it is require to validate issuer while using Passport Azure AD B2C

Comment: Check IDTokenValidaiton article @ http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation, this article will tell you what exactly and why

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it can decide that whether you whether validate the iss claim in id_token. Here is the explaination:

> **validateIssuer (Conditional)**
>
> Required to set to false if you don't want to validate issuer, default
>   value is true. We validate the `iss` claim in `id_token` against user
>   provided `issuer` values and the issuer value we get from
>   tenant-specific endpoint. If you use common endpoint for
>   `identityMetadata` and you want to validate `issuer`, then you have to
>   either provide issuer, or provide the tenant for each login request
>   using `tenantIdOrName` option in passport.authenticate.

For more detials about the passport options , youcan refer to [this article](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#513-options-available-for-passportauthenticate).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the issuer because many services can generate tokens but you only want to trust certain source(s).

**For example:**

**A:** `"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[your app guid]/v2.0"`

vs

**B:** `"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[my app guid]/v2.0"`

vs

**C:** `"iss": "https://a.malicious.site.com/v2.0"`

You don't want to allow tokens issued by **B** nor **C** but you do want to accept tokens issued by **A**.